# How to get idToken from Expo GoogleSignIn API (expo v32)?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I am trying to setup native Google authentication on react-native using Expo [GoogleSignIn](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/google-sign-in/) API, but can't get idToken for authorized Google User.

It has accessToken in response, but not idToken.

So I am using some straigtforward code like

```
const result = await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
                isOfflineEnabled: true,
                isPromptEnabled: true,
                //webClientId: 'webClientId',
                clientId // now testing only on Android, so this is irrelevant
                });
console.log(result);
```

Example response:

```
 Object {
    "auth": Object {
      "accessToken": "accessToken",
      "accessTokenExpirationDate": null,
      "idToken": null,  // here is the problem!
      "refreshToken": null,
    },
    "displayName": "Danila Tsvetkov",
    "email": "email@email",
    "firstName": "Danila",
    "hostedDomain": undefined,
    "lastName": "Tsvetkov",
    "serverAuthCode": null,
    "uid": "uid",
  }
```

At the same time [Google](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/google/) OAuth API returns not only accessToken, but also idToken and refreshToken.

Everything else works fine, like authorization and sign in flow.

Maybe the problem is with serverAuthCode?

Tried to put webClientId, api stops working properly. Added SHA1 to google-services ([more info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/224)), didn't help. Changing other params like "isOfflineEnabled" also doesn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this

```
const result = await Google.logInAsync({
          androidClientId: "android id"
          iosClientId: 'Ios Id',
          scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
        });
```

then

```
 if (result.type === 'success') {
          console.log(result.idToken);
//or
          Alert.alert(result.idToken);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (result.type === 'success') {
     console.log(result.user.auth);
}
```

this is because we are using google-sign-in, instead of expo-google-app-auth

so in conclusion, use result.user.auth, but before that, your code should look something like this

```js
signInAsync = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync();
      const result = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
      if (result.type === 'success') {
        
        this.onSignIn(result.user.auth);
        return result.user.auth;
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert('login: Error:' + message);
    }
  };
```