# When I do Google authentication on Android, the idToken becomes NULL

Tags: expo

I do have one problem.

I have searched for events with similar problems, but none of them have led to a solution.

When I do Google authentication on Android, the idToken becomes NULL.

Are there any comrades who have solved this problem?

```
import * as GoogleSignIn from 'expo-google-sign-in';

    await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
        clientId: String(Config.IOS_CLIENT_ID),
    });

    const isAvailability = await GoogleSignIn.getPlayServiceAvailability();

    if (isAvailability) {
        const { type, user } = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
        console.log(user?.auth);

        // {"idToken": null, "refreshToken": null}
    }
```

[How to get idToken from Expo GoogleSignIn API (expo v32)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564459/how-to-get-idtoken-from-expo-googlesignin-api-expo-v32)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `webClientId` instead of `clientId` in `initAsync`
It worked for me.

```
 await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
        webClientId: String(Config.WEB_CLIENT_ID),
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I'll try it right away.

Comment: Hi, you should pass in the web client id (I pasted from the question, didn't check that carefully), not the IOS client id, I just edited my answer.